# Return Function using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, ssms

My Current table is:

```
USERID  Department    NAME           actualdate
 522    xyz department  John Wayne    2/17/14 8:34
 522    xyz department  John Wayne    2/17/1411:21
 789    xyz department  Bill Smith    2/17/14 9:41
 789    xyz department  Bill Smith    2/17/14 11:16
 789    xyz department  Bill Smith    2/17/14 11:50
 789    xyz department  Bill Smith    2/17/14 12:18
 856    xyz department  Raul Castil   2/17/14 9:25
```

I want to create a function that allows me to enter the user id and return the data from that user.  However, I would like to take the first row and grab the actual date and then  store it in a column'check in' and the also take the last row  and store it in a column call it 'check out'.

Basically for each day I want to record the user check in time and check out time for each day.

This is what I  have so far"

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEmployeeTime]
(   
@useridd int
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    useridd int,
    deptname varchar(max),
    emplname varchar(100),
    actualDate datetime,
    checkIn datetime,--first row of the actual date goes here
    checkOut datetime -- last row of the actual date goes here
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE  @userid int,@checkin datetime, @checkout datetime;
    DECLARE @useridAndDate   varchar(max), @useridAndDate2 varchar(max);

    DECLARE Curs CURSOR FOR 
    select ch.USERID AS useridd,ch.CHECKTIME as actualdate
    from CHECKINOUT ch
    left join USERINFO ui on ui.USERID=ch.USERID
    left join DEPARTMENTS dep on dep.DEPTID=ui.DEFAULTDEPTID

 OPEN Curs;
 FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO  @useridd, @actualdate;
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

 ---so confuse here to loop through rows to record only first and last row.
   set @useridAndDate= @useridd + @actualdate
   --if @useridAndDate != @useridAndDate2
   --begin
   --end

FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @useridd,@actualdate
close Curs;
deallocate Curs;
Return;

END
```

I want the end result to look like this:

```
USERID    Department       NAME    actualdate       checkin       checkout    
 522     xyz department   John Wayne    2/17/14 8:34   2/17/14 8:34   2/17/14 11:21
 789     xyz department   Bill Smith    2/17/14 9:41   2/17/14 9:41   2/17/14 12:18
 856     xyz department   Raul Castil   2/17/14 9:25   2/17/14 9:25
```

Comment: You don't need to use cursor. What version of server are you use?

Answer (score 1):

> There is no need of Cursor for this. You just need to partition
>   maximum and minimum of each User and just take Distinct of them

```
SELECT DISTINCT USERID,Department,NAME,FIR checkTime,
CASE WHEN FIR=SEC THEN NULL ELSE SEC END checkOut 
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
    MIN(CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME)) OVER (PARTITION BY(USERID))FIR, 
    MAX(CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME)) OVER (PARTITION BY(USERID))SEC 
    FROM TimePunch
)TAB
```

Comment: I've tried this.. However this is not taking into account the days. With this Query, If on Feb 13 i started at 8 am and left home at 6pm and If i came to work on Feb 14 at 9 am and left at 7pm. This query will only capture 8am on feb 13 and 7pm for feb 14. for each day i need to capture check in and check out

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a GROUP BY.

Cursors have significant overheads, and while useful for programmatic control, they're often not best suited to answer set-based queries.

The part that has `DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, actualdate))` just truncates that value to the start of the day, so I can get checkins and checkout on different dates.  I've assumes it's DATETIME datatype of some sort, and rounded it used a method that works in pretty much all versions of SQL Server (as you didn't specify which you're using).

```
SELECT
  USERID,
  Department,
  NAME,
  DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, actualdate))   AS date,
  MIN(CHECKTIME)                                  AS checkIn,
  MAX(CHECKTIME)                                  AS checkOut
FROM
  CHECKINOUT
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
```

Note: If any of the date fields are strings, this may have problems.  I would then strongly suggest altering things to make them DATETIME / TIME / DATE fields.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't allow grouping by column ordinals, you need to state the columns, this will give the wrong result when there is only one entry (i.e. `MAX(CheckTime)` will give the checkin time), you need a further check to ensure there is both a checkin and checkout, i.e. `CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN MAX(CheckTime) END`